# Sqlite IN Clause with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, nsarray

I need to do a Select statement using the IN clause with an NSArray in Objective-C. Something like this

```
NSArray *countries = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"USA", @"Argentina", @"England", nil];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement =
    [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select currencies from money where country IN countries] UTF8String];

....
```

where IN countries is the NSArray with the string values. Is this posible?

Comment: Please take a moment to revisit your previous [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1424334/user1424334?tab=questions) and accept some answers where applicable. You just need to click the large check box to the left of the answer you find best. It's the polite thing to do on StackOverflow. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the query string to :

```
const char *sqlStatement =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select currencies from money where country IN ('%@')",[countries componentsJoinedByString:@"','"]] UTF8String];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, almost there. When I output the query I see the array values in different lines, returning no results:
    select currencies from money where country IN('
        USA','
        Argentina','
        England')

When I make this same query on a sqlite client It returns no result, but when I make the same query in a same line the query works fine returning the correct results. Is there any way componentsJoinedByString outputs the string in a same line? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1424334 Try this : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select currencies from money where country IN ('%@')",[countries componentsJoinedByString:@"','"]]

Comment: @user1424334 did you try this??

Comment: That is the correct way to make the select statement. However previously of doing that I had to remove spaces a newlines from the string.